# How can I remove the corresponding Y values that correspond to the deleted outliers in X columns in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-cleaning, outliers

I have used the following method to remove outliers in my X variables prior to modelling:

```
z = np.abs(stats.zscore(X))
X = X[(z < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

How can I make it so the corresponding values in the Y column are deleted so that I can continue with my modelling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the mask then apply it on both `X` and `Y`.

```
z = np.abs(stats.zscore(X))
mask = (z < 3).all(axis=1)
X = X[mask]
Y = Y[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks @Guimote but does this delete the values in Y that correspond to the outliers in my X's or just the outliers in Y?

Comment: It deletes the values in `Y` that correspond to the outliers in `X` because that is the criteria we gave when creating the `z` array, so that's pretty handy when your data is really XY and not two independent X and Y. It keeps the logical link between (x,  y) pairs intact so to say.